# Cannot search while changing datagridview column name

Tags: c#, winforms

i changed the column name of datagridview now the search query is not working 
it says cannot find column name emp_f_name in query (2) whats the problem in the second query

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(); 
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LFC;Initial Catalog=contactmgmt;Integrated Security=True"; 

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT emp_id as 'EmployeeID' , emp_f_name as 'First Name', emp_l_name as 'Last Name',emp_alias as 'Alias Name',emp_contact_no as 'Contact No',emp_address as 'Address',emp_company as 'Company Name',emp_bdate as 'DOB',emp_email as'EmailID' FROM cntc_employee",con); 

dt = new DataTable(); 
sda.Fill(dt); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

dv.RowFilter = string.Format("emp_f_name LIKE '%{0}%'",textBox9.Text);
```

Comment: Do you execute your query in the DataAdapter (e.g `sda.Fill(...)`)? A DataView.RowFilter will only filter records already loaded from a dataSource!

Comment: yes i have included sda.fill
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LFC;Initial Catalog=contactmgmt;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT emp_id as 'EmployeeID' , emp_f_name as 'First Name', emp_l_name as 'Last Name',emp_alias as 'Alias Name',emp_contact_no as 'Contact No',emp_address as 'Address',emp_company as 'Company Name',emp_bdate as 'DOB',emp_email as'EmailID' FROM cntc_employee",con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: I added your code to the question. your datagridView is using the dataTable as datasource. It should **use the dataView as dataSource** to display the filtered results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used alias for `emp_f_name` i.e. `First Name`, either remove the alias or use the alias. You need to put the multi-word alias / column in **square brackets**, like [`First Name]`.

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("[First Name] LIKE '%{0}%'",textBox9.Text);
```

Comment: dv.RowFilter = string.Format("'First Name' LIKE '%{0}%'",textBox9.Text);
i missed the 'First name ' single inverted comma but still it doesnot search

Comment: @skates008 try **String.Format("[First Name] LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox9.Text);**

Comment: Thanks #Phoenix, I had that in mind and now I Just confirmed that.